# React TinyMCE with custom color palette for setting text color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

On this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-iymm9a?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FRichEditor.jsx (you can play around with it)

I have a dummy `TinyMCE` text editor.

These are the main files:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import RichEditor from "./RichEditor";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('Continue the sentence ... ');

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    console.log({ value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <RichEditor
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <hr />
      <pre>{value}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**RichEditor.jsx**

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


export default function RichEditor({value, onChange, className}) {

  const [innerValue, setInnerValue] = useState(value ?? '');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== innerValue) {
      setValue(value);
    }
  }, [value, innerValue]);

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setInnerValue(newValue);
    onChange && onChange(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      className={className}
      value={innerValue}
      init={{
        height: 400,
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic forecolor backcolor',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top: 30px }'
      }}
      onEditorChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

**What I need is:** Change the current color palette when setting the text color. Especifically I want only the following three colors available: `{ #f00, #0f0, #00f }`.

Currently I'm having this color palette...

[image]

Any idea on how to do that?

Please feel free to post a forked link with the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution provided pretty much what you need in plain JavaScript if you were using the plugin outside of React.

Here's the solution in React:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vlnzr7?file=src/RichEditor.jsx

```
return (
<Editor
  className={className}
  value={innerValue}
  init={{
    height: 400,
    menubar: false,
    color_map: [
      '#f00', 'Red',
      '#0f0', 'Green',
      '#00f', 'Blue',
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic forecolor backcolor',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top: 30px }'
  }}
  onEditorChange={handleChange}
/>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `color_map` option will allow you to do this:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/user-formatting-options/#example-using-color_map

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'forecolor backcolor',
  color_map: [
    '000000', 'Black',
    '808080', 'Gray',
    'FFFFFF', 'White',
    'FF0000', 'Red',
    'FFFF00', 'Yellow',
    '008000', 'Green',
    '0000FF', 'Blue'
  ]
});
```

Comment: Could you please fork my link on StackBlitz with your solution and test it? Thanks!